# The getProperty is returning null even after loading the property file in Java

Tags: java, dynamic-class-loaders

What is wrong in the below code. Everything seems correct and no exceptions when executing. I have double verified that the test property value is there in config.properties file.

```
@BeforeClass
public void propertyLoading() {
    System.out.println("in beforeclass");

    prop = new Properties();
    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    try {
        System.out.println("path : "+classLoader.getResource("config.properties").getFile().toString());
        input = new FileInputStream(new File(classLoader.getResource("config.properties").getFile()));
        prop.load(input);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (input != null)
            input.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("test       : "+System.getProperty("test"));
}
```

config.properties file contents below;

```
test=aaaa
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using the System properties, this is not the same as runtime properties that you are trying to use

```
System.getProperty
```

while you should be calling your Properties object that you created a few lines above

```
prop.getProperty("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read your properties from System.getProperty() call

```
System.setProperties(prop);
```

after reading your properties from file

(On the sideline, use try with resources when possible https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)